# How to extend a spring repository bean, keeping existing dsl query method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

In my current implementation, I using a spring repository bean, which is defined in dependant jar. So lets say, this is my `ModelRepository` defined in dependant jar

```
@Repository
public interface ModelRepository extends CustomModelRepository{
  Optional<Model> findByModelId(String id);     
}
```

The `CustomModelRepository` and `CustomModelRepositoryImpl`, are also defined in the dependent jar. Now, in the current implementation, I want to use this spring repository, to also have another dsl query method. So lets say, I want to add and use query method

```
List<Model> findByAnotherModelId(String id);
```

My question is how can I acheive this without adding the above query method in dependent code, because of module upgrade issues.

Comment: What about creating and interface that extends ModelRepository ?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, yes I thought of this, and I tried this way. But dsl query methods in `CustomModelRepostory` are not recognized then.

Answer (score 1):

So I was finally able to solve the problem, avoiding catashprohic changes.

**Step 1:**

Create a interface that extends the main repository bean from the dependant jar, and your required dsl query method. This repository now has all dsl methods that `ModelRepository`.

```
@Repository
public interface WrapperModelRepository extends ModelRepository{
  List<Model> findByAnotherModelId(String id);    
}
```

**Step 2:**. Now our work was over if there was no custom query methods inherited in `ModelRepository`. But we have to support the custom query method, defined in `CustomModelRepository`. If we dont do that, then our wrapper repository breaks at bean startup, as it is unable to find implmenentation of the custom query method, defined in `CustomModelRepositoryImpl`. So for that, we need to create another Impl class for wrapper repository, that can just wrap the implementaion of the custom query method.

```
@Component
public class WrapperModelRepositoryImpl implments WrapperModelRepository {

  private CustomModelRepositoryImpl customModelRepository;

  public WrapperModelRepositoryImpl(CustomModelRepositoryImpl repository){
    this.customModelRepository = repository;
  }

  public Model exactQueryMethodNameDeclaredInCustomModelRepository(){
    return customModelRepository.exactQueryMethodNameDeclaredInCustomModelRepository()
  }
}
```

Now, our required bean is created unless you forget to mention this ( your current wrapper implementaion) package, in your `@EnableJpaRepositories` repositories, for spring to create repositories for you.

Comment: May I ask about the "implements" part in the class declaration? looks like you need to implement the "derived" method 'findByAnotherModel' in this class otherwise it won't compile

Answer (score 0):

There is, so called, a service layer, i.e. ModelService class that is usually used for all business logic of app. There you can define which Model instance should go to the repository methods for dealing with persistence. 
(p.s. maybe i did not get your issue right so please specify that if so...)

Comment: yes, I am aware of this, but the question is is that it is already defined in dependant jar(3rd party jar), I dont want to do it again just to add a single custom query that will be exclusively used in my application. So I am looking for ways to extend that existing spring-data-jpa respository.